# How to get the image into data that you can save to SQL

Tags: php, sql, image, base64, input-type-file

```
if(isset($_POST["imageuploader"])){ //Is submitted
    if ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']){ //LINE 3
        $data   = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $base64 = base64_encode($data);
        $item   = inputSanitize($_POST['item']);


        $updateImage = $odb->prepare("UPDATE `items` SET `image` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;");
        $updateImage->BindValue(1, $base64);
        $updateImage->BindValue(2, $item);
        $success = true;
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Please add an image.";
    }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is that `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` is apparently an undefined index:

> Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/html/staff/imageupdater.php on line 3

However, I have this in my form:

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
```

`file_uploads = On` in my `php.ini` & the file I'm uploading is gif.

Comment: On line 2, put `print_r($_FILES)`, and post back the results here

Comment: do you  use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag?

Comment: Array ( )  And no Dave, but I added it and the array said "Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => Assassin_Star.gif [type] => image/gif [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpZjeeXV [error] => 0 [size] => 2357 ) )" so, atleast we're getting somewhere, haha.

Comment: make sure your form is multipart `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or no file is uploaded....

Comment: It is however, not uploading the base64_encode, I'm going to var_dump the $base64 and see what I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you are missing the enctype in your form tag.,

```
 <form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without that no file is uploaded and the `$_FILES` is not populated, hence the undefined `image` index.

Comment: Sure, easy mistake.